# Vue.js result not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

With how I currently have the code i'm receiving an error that "result" isn't defined but if I define it in the data area I get an error that you can't duplicate keys.

```
<template>

<form>
  <label for="weightLifted">Weight Lifted</label>
  <input type="text" id="weightLifted" v-model="weightLifted">
  <br/>
  <label for="reps">Number of Reps</label>
  <input type="text" id="reps" v-model="reps">
  <br/>
  <label for="result">Max</label>
  <input type="text" id="result" v-model="result">
</form>

</template>
<style>


</style>
<script>
  export default {

    data() {
      return {
        weightLifted: '',
        reps: '',


      }
    },
    computed: {
      result: function () {
        return result = this.weightLifted * (1 + (this.reps / 30));
      }
    }
  }

</script>
```

Comment: what specifically is the error being written to your console?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you an error: 
`<input type="text" id="result" v-model="result">`

a v-model can not be set on computed, unless you have a getter AND a setter.

I'm not sure what you *want* to happen if a user edits that field, but you should either define it as a value, and not have it editable, or define rules for what should happen

here is an example using the setter to calucate the `weightLifted` from the the `Max` update

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      weightLifted: '',
      reps: '',
    }
  },
  computed: {
    result: {
      get() {
        return this.weightLifted * (1 + (this.reps / 30));
      },
      set(newVal) {
        this.weightLifted = newVal / (1 + (this.reps / 30))
      }
    }
  }
})
```

fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/m27pankg/1/

Comment: uses the modifier= `v-model.number` will be better, `type="number"` will make the input only allow number and related math syntax, but the value will be still one string.

Comment: I find neither are perfect, but either is better than none. Ideal solution IMHO would be to use a watch to sanitize